# iOS check if databse is already created and choose between to .sqlite files to load

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, ios6

I'm developing an iOS application that uses coredata. I have 2 .sqlite databases that should be loaded on the start of the application. One database has english information and the other has Portuguese information. I want my application to show only the first time that the application runs the selection of the language, and then the corresponding database should be loaded. After that I want another view to be loaded and the language selection should not appear again.

So far, I have my application that loads only one database at the start of the app. Can someone give me tips on how to do it? Sorry for the question not to be very specific :s

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Store user's selection of language either in the keychain or NSUserDefault.

Comment: In appdelegate check is it's first load of appication (u can use NSUserDefaults to set some value at first launch) and load chosen language file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to allow the user to choose his language and then set up a new NSPersistentStore with a specific .sqlite file as seed data.

You would do something like this (pardon the pseudocode)

```
if (/*user chose English*/) {

  __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

  [self addSeedDataNamed: @"English.sqlite" toCoordinator:__persistentStoreCoordinator];

}else if (/*user chose portuguese*/){
  [self addSeedDataNamed: @"Portuguese.sqlite" toCoordinator:__persistentStoreCoordinator];
}

- (void) addSeedDataNamed:(NSString *)name toCoordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)storeCoordinator
{
  NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:name];

  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption, nil];
  [storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
}
```

Answer mostly taken from here:
http://blog.atwam.com/blog/2012/05/11/multiple-persistent-stores-and-seed-data-with-core-data/

Comment: Thanks:) But how do I hide the view that allows the selection of the language on the second run of the app, and then transit to the adequate view? Thanks

Comment: You would need to save their choice to disk and then check when the app boots up.  So when I tap english, then the app should save "English" as my choice in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].

Then you can check in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: if NSUserDefaults has the choice and send the user to a different view controller.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i